# Azure Mobile Service login error with database and "master" user

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I've been using Azure Mobile Services with my apps without much issue, but then today when I tried to pull from the service I get this error:

> Exception=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open
>   database "master" requested by the login. The login failed. Login
>   failed for user 'JVlSvKwDpdLogin_*********'.

I've never had this issue come up before, and I'm only connecting to my mobile service in code like this:

```
public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
        "https://<webservicename>.azure-mobile.net/",
        "<YOUR-API-KEY-HERE>"
    );
```

Before this error happened, I never supplied a username or password. I've seen some solutions where they've created a user for the database but I don't want to create one right now since we're still in testing and I'd rather be able to use the service without one for now. Is this an issue with mobile service, or an issue with the database?

**UPDATE**

As suggested by Matt's answer below, I found the MS_ConnectionString in the Azure portal. I then connected to the 'master' database on my Azure SQL server and searched for the login above. I changed the password to the one found in the connection string using

```
ALTER LOGIN <login> WITH password='<password-found-in-connection-string>';
```

But now I get this error:

> Exception=System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the failure. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'JVlSvKwDpdLogin_***********'.

I haven't change anything with the connection string or the web.config file for my AzureMobileService project.

web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MS_TableConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=    (localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-CoverageTool.AzureMobileService-20140910083006.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-CoverageTool.AzureMobileService-20140910083006;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

MobileContext:

```
private const string connectionStringName = "Name=MS_TableConnectionString";

    public MobileServiceContext()
        : base(connectionStringName)
    {
    }
```

Connection String

> Data Source=*********.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=sbpconsulting_db;User ID=*********Login_sbpconsulting;Password=****************;Asynchronous Processing=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;

Comment: Can you paste the connection string (minus username and password please) that you find in the portal?

Comment: Sure thing, I just added the connection string. Just to reitterate, this is the connection string that was auto-created along with the Mobile Service, so I made no changes to it. All I did was copy and paste the password when trying to ALTER LOGIN from a database script, but still get login errors.

Answer (score 9):

This error could also appear if your Entity Framework database initializers are not compatible with the permissions of the database user that your Azure Mobile Service is using.

For example, when you create database for a Azure Mobile Service, Azure automatically creates a DB user for your service. This user does not have admin permissions - it can generally read and write data to a table. In that case, if you are using DropCreateDatabaseAlways DB initializer your user will not have sufficient permission to actually drop the database and you may see the error that you have mentioned.

There are new initializers that were introduced to work with limited set of permissions:

- ClearDatabaseSchemaAlways - use instead of DropCreateDatabaseAlways
- ClearDatabaseSchemaIfModelChanges - use instead of DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

Comment: I was having problems running an Azure Mobile Service in which I had a database with two schemas because another Azure Mobile Service was also using the same database (each service automatically gets its own schema). So, using ClearDatabaseSchemaAlways<T> (or ClearDatabaseSchemaIfModelChanges<T>) instead of the usual DropCreateDataBaseAlways<T> is what fixed it for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of one thing that may be the problem. Windows Azure Databases only allow specific ip addresses that you have white listed before hand.

So if you are trying to run your app from a different internet connection or if your ip address has changed then that might be your issue.

Try accessing your database directly on your Azure Management Console and allow your ip address access to the database server.

Azure always needs authentication so check your applications app.config / web.config file for credentials.

More code-based information would have been helpful to make this answer more than a shot in the dark.

Comment: I'm able to access the management portal and have checked the IP addresses. Sorry for the lack of code, but let me know what you might want/need to see.The only place in my client app (Windows Phone 8.1 app) I have made a connection to the mobile service is in App.xaml.cs shown in the code above. Were you talking about the web.config of the mobileservice project?

Comment: Yes, I meant the web.config file. Please post the file mark up, sometimes credentials are embedded in there in sample applications.

Answer (score 0):

Do you control the SQL login? Do you have other databases hosted on the same SQL Azure server? 
That error is happening on the backend between your service tier and the database and won't be impacted by anything in the client application(s).

The account setup in the portal doesn't have the permissions it needs. Either you have found a bug, someone has revoked the permissions for that user, or the password has changed.

Based on the error message, I'd say it is the latter issue and you need to find out what the password is and make sure it is in sync with the MS_TableConnectionString setting on the Configure tab of your mobile service. You might have to reset the password for that login on SQL and also update the connection string just to make sure they are the same.

Comment: I've found the connection string and the password it's using for the user above. I ran the query "ALTER LOGIN <user> WITH password='<password>';" using the password in the connection string. But still no luck. Is there a step that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that may be a problem is EF migrations. Have you changed your model and enabled migrations? This would all run fine on your local instance and you could add migrations and update database. When you go to deploy though you'd want to enable automatic migrations to make sure the SQL Azure DB also gets the migrations applied. I've seen people have issues with this same error message (ProviderIncompatible) when it was a migrations issue. 
To enable auto migrations make sure you go into the configuration.cs file and change the line of code that sets boolean property to "false" by default to "true".

Comment: I haven't enabled migrations yet on since we're still in development so I've been nuking the database if needed. But I'll try that first and see if it fixes it. Also, I did notice that the database has changed from the free "web" edition to the "basic" edition on Monday when this problem started. I'm wondering if that caused it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue.
My Mobile Service was connecting to my Azure SQL Database called 'Diary'. This was working ok for a few weeks. Then, without any changes from my side , I started getting the error :

> Exception=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "master" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'HwRkAPcQLyLogin_xxxService'.

I fixed the issue by:

- adding the user  'HwRkAPcQLyLogin_xxxService' to my 'Diary' database
- assigning db_owner permissions to the 'HwRkAPcQLyLogin_xxxService' user

I used this handy tool to manage the Azure Users:
https://aumc.codeplex.com/

I did not have to change anything in the master database.